# Save Text and Drop down Selection to Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store text entered in the textarea and the option selected from a drop down menu to Firebase. I have linked my code below. The File that is uploaded is being saved, however, the text and options selected are not being saved to Firebase database. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the javascript code:

```
/*jslint plusplus: true*/
 var index = 0;
var Email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
var EmailU = Email[index];



var uploader = document.getElementById("uploader");
var fileButton = document.getElementById("fileButton");
//Listen for file selection

fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // Get File 
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    //Create a storage ref

    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(Email + file.name);
    /** folder name will be email**/
    //Upload file 

    var task = storageRef.put(file);
    //Update progress bar
    task.on('state_changed',
        function progress(snapshot) {
            var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            uploader.value = percentage;
        },
        function complete() {
        sessionStorage.setItem(file.name);
        });
});
}


//function to gets the value from the html and stores them into an array 
function AddMed() {
'use strict';
//Create array of values from html

var database = firebase.database();

function writeUserData(userId, name, email, image) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + EmailU).set({
        MedName: document.getElementById("MTitle").value, // title of Med
        description: document.getElementById("Adescription").value, //descripton of Med
        Type: document.getElementById("TypeSelect").value, // Type
        //Start: document.getElementById("AStart").value, //when does it start
        //End: document.getElementById("AEnd").value //when does it end    
    });
    index++;
}

}
```

The html code is this:

```
 <h1><b>Medicine Schedule</b></h1>
<!---------------------------------------------- START of Form ---------------------------------------------->
<div id="form">
    <form>
        Name of Medicine <input type="text" id="MTitle" size="50" name="MedicineTitle">
        <br>
        <br> Descritption:
        <br> <textarea id="Adescription" rows="2" cols="50" name="AnnouncementDescription" placeholder="Provide a description of what the medicine is. "></textarea>
        <br>
        <br> Type: <select id="TypeSelect"> 
                <option>Pill</option>
                <option>Syrup</option>
                <option>Drop</option>
                <option>Cream</option>
                    </select>
        <br>
        <br> Start Date: <input type="date" id="AStart" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="MeetingTime">
        <br>
        <br> End Date: <input type="date" id="AEnd" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="MeetingTime">
        <br>
        <br>
    </form>
</div>
<!------------------------------------ END of Medicine Form ------------------------------------------>
<div id="progress">
    <progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress>
    <input type="file" value="upload" id="fileButton" />
</div>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" onclick="AddMed()"> Submit Medicine</button>
```

Comment: at line Type: document.getElementById("TypeSelect").value  (no comma at the end). Fix this first.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: fixed. I'm not getting any error it just doesn't save

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the function writeUserData().

```
    function AddMed() {
'use strict';
//Create array of values from html

var database = firebase.database();

function writeUserData(userId, name, email, image) {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + EmailU).set({
        MedName: document.getElementById("MTitle").value, // title of Med
        description: document.getElementById("Adescription").value, //descripton of Med
        Type: document.getElementById("TypeSelect").value // Type
        //Start: document.getElementById("AStart").value, //when does it start
        //End: document.getElementById("AEnd").value //when does it end    
    });
    index++;
}

writeUserData();

}
```

Comment: I tried that however it still does not work :/ Any other ideas?

Comment: Add addme() inside change listener as well.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by change listener?

Comment: see my other answer pls

Answer (score 0):

You did not call AddMed inside the event lister. Try adding below and see if it works.

```
    fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    ....your code...

    AddMed();
   }
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Edited.